# Refresh listview in fragment tabs from actionbar

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have a `FragmentActivity` that contains 2 tabs, each with a fragment and i have an `ActionBar` with refresh and search items, is it possible to use these items on the fragments inside the tabs?

I use `SwipeLayout` for refreshing each fragment, i want for the user to have both options to choose from.

Comment: easiest way is to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: yes you could if you use static method to refresh the adapter outside of its fragment. but i don't suggest this if your lists are dynamically change. i suggest you in each of your fragment have different menus and has each item do its job within its fragment.